# Я девушку(,) по-настоящему красивую(,) ещё не видал

Tags: запятые

Моя теория такая, что, даже есть нельзя убрять оброт, но он посерёдке, — запятая. То есть:

> Я девушку, по-настоящему красивую, ещё не видал.

Но если он в конце — беззапятной вариант.

> Я не видел ещё-таки девушку по-настоящему красивую.

Что думаете? Правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможны **варианты:**

**Обособление:**  *Я не видел ещё-таки дЕвушку, **по-настоящему красИвую.***

**Нет обособления:** *Я не видел ещё-таки девушку / **по-настоЯщему красивую.***

**Примечание.**

Для корректного понимания смысла важны **распространители** (дополнительные структурные элементы).

**Сравнить:**

*Я (еще) не видел дЕвушку, **по-настоящему красИвую.***

*Я (еще) не видел дЕвушку / **по-настоЯщему красивую**.*

Но без "еще" получается **другой смысл и другие решения.**

**ВЫВОД**

Нельзя решать задачи **МЕХАНИЧЕСКИ (формально)**, только по теории и по правилам, но надо их решать для **конкретного предложения** (с учетом теории и правил).

Comment: А про случай, где оборот в середине предложения, вы не упомянули.

Comment: Там очевидное решение. Как все это можно не обособить! Набор слов получится, а не предложение.