# О правиле обособления определительного оборота после определяемого слова

Tags: пунктуация, определения

Вот  **[правило](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/476476/%D0%AF-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B5%D1%89%D1%91-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB)** **обособления определительного оборота**, которое было предложено:

```
    Моя теория такая, что, даже есть нельзя убрать оборот, но он 
    посерёдке,  запятая. То есть: Я девушку, по-настоящему красивую, ещё 
    не видал.
```

*Я дЕвушку, **по-настоящему красИвую**, ещё не видАл.*

**По смыслу** оборот действительно нельзя убрать. Верно и то, что оборот здесь обособляется. **Но всегда ли верно это правило?**

Comment: А если нельзя убрать без потери смысла, почему тогда обособляется?

Comment: Убрать нельзя, но обособить можно.  Сравните с придаточным:  Я дЕвушку,  которая была бы по-настоящему красива...,  Девушку можно определить любой конструкцией.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуем **распространить** предложение, и тогда возможны **варианты:**

(1) *Я девушку **по-настоЯщему красивую** / в своей жизни еще не видАл.*

**Нет обособления,** подчёркивается **степень признака.**

(2) *Я дЕвушку,  **по-настоящему красИвую,**  в своей жизни еще не видАл.*

**Обособление**, подчеркивается **сам признак.**

**Вывод**

Сложно придумать **универсальное** правило, но нужно проводить **анализ** каждого **конкретного** предложения.